# An error occurred while starting application?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, asp.net-core-webapi, aspnetboilerplate

I have downloaded Asp.net boiler plate template and published it to Amazon using Elastic bean stalk.

But now I am seeing error as "An error occurred while starting application".

http://kphomewebhost-dev.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/

Please let me know if there are any guide line for publishing asp.net boiler plate.

Comment: Check if it's running on your local. See if it expects any env variables. if all these are good then try checking the errors after logging into the server.

Comment: also, please be much clear on the specifics next time. else your question may be termed as not relevant. @krunalparmar

Comment: Its running fine on local, only on AWS its failing. I  am not sure where to find error logs in AWS. Seems like it does not have require framework to run application. If I can find log I can get some idea.

Comment: you should be able to log into aws via ssh. try checking on that. you will be able to find more reasons. I am tagging this with aws as well. You might find better help that way

Comment: Have you followed [Deploying an ASP.NET Core Application with AWS Elastic Beanstalk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/dotnet-core-tutorial.html)?

Comment: thanks @TaoZhou I will take a look at it.

Comment: check Logs\Logs.txt to see application logs for aspnetboilerplate